# How to integrate spylog with tomcat 7 and hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, tomcat7

I need to integrate spylog to my existing Java Web-start application which runs on tomcat 7 and uses hibernate.

Following is the configuration details:
**spy.log file:**

```
realdriver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dbname</property>
    <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
    <property name="connection.password">admin</property>


    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property> 
    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0--> 
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">5</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">20</property> <!-- seconds -->
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property> <!-- seconds --> 

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <!-- for debug purposes set show_sql property true -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.app.dao.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory | Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at com.app.server.dao.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at com.app.server.dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:39)
    at com.app.server.dao.CacheDaoImpl.openSession(CacheDaoImpl.java:404)
    at com.app.server.dao.CacheDaoImpl.loadCache(CacheDaoImpl.java:94)
    at com.app.server.dao.CacheDaoImpl.init(CacheDaoImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:105)
    at clientframework.server.Server.initFactory(Server.java:156)
    at clientframework.server.Server.init(Server.java:176)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 63 more
```

I am not getting any clue about this error, can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your connection.url must be this format:

```
jjdbc:sqlserver://myUrl:port;databaseName=my_database
```

In your example code, is this:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbname</property>
```

Regards and good luck

References:

[A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528004/a-resourcepool-could-not-acquire-a-resource-from-its-primary-factory-or-source)

[how to configure hibernate config file for sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585544/how-to-configure-hibernate-config-file-for-sql-server)