# Does hibernate SessionFactory.openSession() wait for a database connection to be available from pool

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, c3p0

Does hibernate `SessionFactory.openSession()` wait for a database connection to be available from pool ?

I assumed it did, but I have customer with this exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
    at com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.beginTransaction(HibernateUtil.java:192)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongMatcher.call(MusicBrainzSongMatcher.java:83)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongMatcher.call(MusicBrainzSongMatcher.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MainAnalyserService$EnsureIncreaseCountIfRunOnCallingThread.rejectedExecution(MainAnalyserService.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MainAnalyserService.submit(MainAnalyserService.java:121)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzMetadataMatcher.processMetadataFailedToMatch(MusicBrainzMetadataMatcher.java:107)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzMetadataMatcher.call(MusicBrainzMetadataMatcher.java:381)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzMetadataMatcher.call(MusicBrainzMetadataMatcher.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:689)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
```

making me think it isn't, or is it waiting for a certain time and then giving up, I am using **Hibernate 4.3.11** with **C3p0** and **H2 1.5**

My Hibernate config is

```
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size","1");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size","50");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements","3000");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","2000");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection","50");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period","3000");
    config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts","10");
```

Comment: "A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source"

This normally means that the pool can't get any db connection, meaning there is probably some configuration or network issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate **SessionFactory** **openSession()** method always opens a new session. you should close this session object once you are done with all the database operations.
Session objects are not thread safe,you should open a new session for each request in multi-threaded environment

base on this refrence 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#openSession()

> Session openSession()
>                       throws HibernateException Open a Session. JDBC connection(s will be obtained from the configured ConnectionProvider
>   as needed to perform requested work.
>
> Returns: The created session. Throws: HibernateException - Indicates a
>   peroblem opening the session; pretty rare here.

also you can check this links to resolve problem:

[A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528004/a-resourcepool-could-not-acquire-a-resource-from-its-primary-factory-or-source)

[com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465872/com-mchange-v2-resourcepool-cannotacquireresourceexception-a-resourcepool-could?lq=1)